# HTTP Status 404 in Spring MVC HandleMapping

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

ı have question with spring mvc. 
ı trying to learn handlerMapping with spring mvc. ı have some bugs
this error 
http://localhost:8080/springmvc/page1

I could not solve the problem 
I'm just trying to learn spring MVC.
**NOTE**
there is 02.01.beanNameHandlerMapping.view folder under jsp folder

```
HTTP Status 404 - /springmvc/WEB-INF/jsp/02.01.beanNameHandlerMapping.view/sayfa1.jsp

    type Status report

message /springmvc/WEB-INF/jsp/02.01.beanNameHandlerMapping.view/sayfa1.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.45`
```

this is my codes

> web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>springmvc</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>               

                /WEB-INF/02.00.appContext.xml

            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/myproject/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

> 02.00.appContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    ">


<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

    <bean name="/page1"  class="_02_01.beanNameUrlHandlerMapping.controller.Page1Controller" />
    <bean name="/page2"  class="_02_01.beanNameUrlHandlerMapping.controller.Page2Controller" />
    <bean name="/page3*" class="_02_01.beanNameUrlHandlerMapping.controller.Page3Controller" />
</beans>
```

> Page1Controller.java

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class Page1Controller extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("02.01.beanNameHandlerMapping.view/sayfa1");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "Hello Page1");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

> sayfa1.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't resolve the problem. How ca I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the answer
but sorry my mistake 02.01.beanNameHandlerMapping.view I left a space in the folder name. 
So it gave error when calling with file. so it cannot find jsp

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the ModelAndView object inside the controller just pass the model name which is sayfa1.